# How can I iterate over an array with foreach without changing the address of the loop variable?

Tags: perl

When I run a simple bit of code like this:

```
my @arr=(1..5);
my $x;
foreach $x (@arr) {
    $x+=10;
}
print "@arr";
```

The result is "11 12 13 14 15" because $x "becomes" each element in the @arr array in the foreach.  Well enough.

But here's my thing... not so much a problem (the solution is easy, but inelegant, and I want my perl to be as elegant as possible).

I wrote a tie module for dealing with COBOL data.  It takes a copybook, parses the fields, and then attaches that to a scalar/string so that access to/from the tied hash will return/set values in the string.  It works wonderfully.

```
my %h,$rec;
my $cb=<<END;
       01 CH-RECORD.
          05 JOB-NUM PIC X.
          05 FILLER  PIC X(76).
          05 REC-TYPE PIC X(2).
END
tie %h, 'COBOLDataTie',$cb,\$rec; #tie the hash to the record via the copybook
```

From there, I can move a COBOL record to $rec and access the COBOL fields with the %h hash.

Again, this works perfectly.  But the problem comes when I want to iterate over, say, an array of COBOL records.  So if after the above code I had something akin to:

```
foreach $rec (@arr) {
    print "Job is ",$h{'JOB-NUM'},"\n";
}
```

it won't work because the foreach actually changes the location of $rec, which breaks the tie on it.  I end up having to do something like this:

```
foreach (@arr) {
    $rec=$_;
    print "Job is ",$h{'JOB-NUM'},"\n";
}
```

Is there any way I can do the "foreach $rec (@arr)" and not break my tied hash?

(And before anyone says, yes I know this begs for a nice object-oriented solution... some day I'll get to that; I just have to find some time first)

EPILOGUE: I revised the TieHash code to, instead of pointing to an external record, it intercepts "special" keys for the hash, among which is 'record'.  So when I assign a record string to $h{'record'} it's the same as loading $rec in the example above.  This is a far better solution, more self-contained.  It also exposes a more OOP-like interface.

Comment: @ikegame I think I see what OP means. Look at the second code block. He's tying `$rec` to the hash ... somehow.

Comment: Why are you using a [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) based module? How is it better than just using an object?

Comment: As I indicated, I hadn't done an OOP version yet... maybe someday if my workload ever lightens.  @simbabque, I'm actually tying to \$rec, not $rec.

Comment: Actually a [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) based module **is** object oriented. Notice that in [Tie::Hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html) the mention of being a "base *class* for tied hashes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best way is to do something like:

```
for (my $i=0;($rec=$arr[$i], $i<@arr);$i++) {
```

Not exactly the elegance I was hoping for, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The interface you decided to create is "assign to `$rec`, then access fields via `%h`". As such, that's exactly what you need to do.

```
for (@arr) {
    $rec = $_;
    print "Job is $h{'JOB-NUM'}\n";
}
```

Sure it looks weird, but that's beause it is weird. This would make more reasonable:

```
for (@arr) {
    my $h = parse($cb, $_);
    print "Job is $h->{'JOB-NUM'}\n";
}
```

You can even do it with minimal changes:

```
sub parse {
    my ($cb, $rec) = @_;
    tie my %h, 'COBOLDataTie', $cb, \$rec; 
    return \%h;
}
```

Comment: The shortcoming to your suggestion is that each record would have to have every field parsed every time.  In a record with hundreds of fields, each of which has to be deconstructed from COBOL format to a regular scalar (including, possibly, EBCDIC-to-ASCII conversion), if I only need 1 or 2 fields in the record, this method would GREATLY slow down processing time.  Using a tied hash allows the code to only convert a field when and as it's used, without having to convert all the fields.  My earlier efforts at this indeed had a parse function in the vein of what you suggest.

Comment: oops, yes, it's not equivalent.

Comment: A more reasonable tied array API might be `tie my %h, 'COBOLDataTie', $cb; $h{$rec}{'JOB-NUM'}`. `$h{rec}` would need to returned a ref to a tied hash.

Comment: I'd tried your third sample above... tying a variable each time a new record is read slows things down quite a bit.  I'd also considered the technique in your comment above with the nested hash... but then my brain started to hurt  :-)  In the end, this really begs for a full-on OOP solution.  But even then, things are limited.  Ever tried "foreach $h{'rec'} (@arr)"?  The compiler chuckles and then questions your parentage!

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle point and easy to overlook in the documentation, but the loop variable in a `foreach` variable is always a new variable, and has nothing to do with any lexical or package variables with the same name anywhere else in the program.

From [`perlsyn`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsyn#Foreach_loops):

> Foreach Loops
>
> The "foreach" loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the
>          variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn.  If the variable
>          is preceded with the keyword "my", then it is lexically scoped, and is
>          therefore visible only within the loop.  Otherwise, **the variable is
>          implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting
>          the loop**.  If the variable was previously declared with "my", it uses
>          that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to
>          the loop.  This implicit localization occurs only in a "foreach" loop.

(emphasis added). That is, the `$rec` in line 3 of this little script has nothing to do with the `$rec` declared in line 1

```
1: my $rec = 'foo';
2: print $rec;                       # 'foo'
3: foreach $rec (@some_list) {
4:     print $rec;                   # something else
5: }
6: print $rec;                       # 'foo' again
```

So if you want to use `\$rec` to influence behavior of your tied hash (though there are certainly other ways to do it), then you are doing the right thing to use a different loop variable and assign `$rec` to it inside the loop.

Comment: Excellent information, thanks.  Doesn't answer my question, unfortunately, but only reinforces that I can't do it the way I want.